# How to integrate Salesforce Opportunity object to Intercom

Tags: salesforce, intercom

Every time the Sales reps have to look up manually the Opp stage of the customer to report the status of the process. keywords are used to tag the conversations to direct the Sales rep for better assistance. How do I use a keyword or tag in the intercom coversations when the customer wants to know about his/her Opportunity stage in the process.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: I figured out that Intercom doesn't support the tracking of the sales process or pipeline. It only supports tracking leads.